# Generate Pdf with docraptor in django

Tags: python, django, pdf

I have a django app in which i have a page the displays some data and images, now i need to convert that HTML page in to pdf, so i am trying to use [Docraptor](http://docraptor.com/try_it_out).

So below is my code/view to generate pdf

```
def generate_report_pdf(request, user_id):
    site = Site.objects.get(id=settings.SITE_ID)
    url = site.domain + reverse('overview', args=[user_id,])
    docraptor = DocRaptor(settings.DOCRAPTOR_API_KEY)
    with open("test.pdf", "wb") as f:
        f.write(docraptor.create({
            'document_url': url,
            'test': True,
            'document_type':'pdf',
        }).content)

    print f,f.name,">>>>>>>>>>>>"
    print type(f),">>>>>>>>>>>>"
    print dir(f),">>>>>>>>>>>>"
    file = open(f, 'r').read()
    return HttpResponse(file, mimetype='application/pdf')
```

**Output:**

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

This error was occurring at the line `file = open(f, 'r').read()`

And out put of the above print statements are

```
<closed file 'test.pdf', mode 'wb' at 0x7faea05a59c0> test.pdf >>>>>>>>>>>>
<type 'file'> >>>>>>>>>>>>
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'close', 'closed', 'encoding', 'errors', 'fileno', 'flush', 'isatty', 'mode', 'name', 'newlines', 'next', 'read', 'readinto', 'readline', 'readlines', 'seek', 'softspace', 'tell', 'truncate', 'write', 'writelines', 'xreadlines']
```

So why am i getting this `Exception Value:  coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found` error and how display the file i got as pdf in django ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this -

```
file = open(f, 'r').read()
```

try

```
file = open(f.name, 'r').read()
```

You are passing the file object whereas the function needs file path/name.